# Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't show external display options

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, gnome-control-center

I am trying to connect my laptop to an external display (TV/projector) using a Ugreen HDMI-to-USB C adapter. This process has worked on my windows system but ubuntu doesn't show this option for me at all in the settings menu, see screenshot:

[image: GNOME display settings]

And running the `xrnadr` command returns the following output despite it being connected to the display:

[image: xrandr output]

I've tried the following:

- Reinstalling gnome-control-center
- Reinstalling unity-control-center
- Updating NVIDIA drivers
- Downgrading NVIDIA drivers
- Changing the ports I connected to

And all of it did not fix the issue. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was trying a bunch of random solutions that I found online and it turns out the issue was with the NVIDIA drivers, as I mentioned in the question I tried upgrading and downgrading but it didn't work. That's because I wasn't finding the correct version to fix this issue which was the 520 NVIDIA driver update. So if you are facing this issue, try playing around with different driver packages for your GPU. Pretty annoying fix to the issue but NVIDIA gonna NVIDIA I guess :)